# what's the meaning of the word stereographic?

Tags: word-meaning, terminology

does anyone know what is the meaning of the word stereographic? like stereographic projection? I want to translate it into another language and I want it to be accurate. it's like drawing something that gives you a 3D-sense? because it's composed of two words. stere- usually means "solid" or "three-dimensional" and graphic means "relating to visual art, especially involving drawing, engraving, or lettering". am I getting it right?

Comment: The word is mostly used in the phrase *stereographic projection*, and it has a specific meaning there; I suggest looking at wikipedia to understand, the article is pretty good in this case (though it starts with a lot of maths). I imagine that other languages have their own terms for the stereographic projection if they have any technical cartography terms.

Comment: I guess that the projection is called stereographic because the ray passes through the whole volume of the sphere (rather than from the centre).